# Concept constrained member function having dependent argument types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I was doing some experiments with concepts, and I was trying to have constrained member functions that must be instantiated only if a concept is satisfied:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Fooable = requires(T o)
{
    o.foo(uint());
};

template <typename T>
concept Barable = requires(T o)
{
    o.bar(uint());
};

class Foo
{
public:
    using FooType = int;
    void foo(uint) {}
};

class Bar
{
public:
    using BarType = double;
    void bar(uint) {}
};

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    void fun(typename T::FooType t) requires Fooable<T> {}
    void fun(typename T::BarType t) requires Barable<T> {}
};

int main()
{
    C<Foo> f;
}
```

This piece of code does not compile both on GCC 11.2 and Clang 14, saying:

```
main.cpp: error: no type named 'BarType' in 'Foo'
main.cpp: error: no type named 'BarType' in 'Foo'
        void fun(typename T::BarType t) requires Barable<T> {}
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
main.cpp: note: in instantiation of template class 'C<Foo>' requested here
        C<Foo> f;
               ^
```

However, since I am declaring a `C` object with `Foo` type, I expect that the member function `fun` with `BarType` would not be instantiated.

Could this be both a GCC and Clang bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to implement this using concepts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `fun` is not a template function, `typename T::BarType` is always instantiated and produces a hard error if `T` does not have a type alias named `BarType`. You might want to do

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    template<Fooable U = T>
      requires requires { typename U::FooType; }
    void fun(typename U::FooType t);
    template<Barable U = T>
      requires requires { typename U::BarType; }
    void fun(typename U::BarType t);
};
```

Given that `BarType` is associated with the concept `Barable`, a more appropriate approach would be to redefine your concepts as (I replaced `uint()` with `0U` because there is no so-called `uint` type in the standard)

```
template<typename T>
concept Fooable = requires(T o) {
  o.foo(0U);
  typename T::FooType;
};

template<typename T>
concept Barable = requires(T o) {
  o.bar(0U);
  typename T::BarType;
};

template <typename T>
class C {
  public:
    template<Fooable F = T>
    void fun(typename F::FooType t);
    template<Barable B = T>
    void fun(typename B::BarType t);
};
```

which requires that types satisfying `Barable` must have a type alias named `BarType`.

Comment: Why the `requires requires` clause? `U` being `Fooable` has already ensured that a `FooType` exists (or a `BarType` in the second case). [simplified version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c420be7f6e00cf00)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou `Fooable` concept does not require a `FooType` to exist.

Comment: I was about to say what you wrote in the edit. `FooType` existence should be covered by the concept. I overlooked that it's missing there.

Comment: I agree for `FooType` being in the concept. I was just not sure how to write it! :)
Many thanks :)